# ZipArchive::extractTo does not work and returns nothing

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have quite simple code to extract zip, it opens fine, but extractTo does not do anything, it does not return true/false or any errors.

What could be wrong?

```
$zipArchive = new \ZipArchive();

$result = $zipArchive->open('../modules/update.zip'); //this is ok, it opens fine

if ($result === TRUE) { 
    $result = $zipArchive->extractTo("../");
    echo $result;  //empty
    $zipArchive ->close();
} else {
    echo "Cant open zip";
}
```

**EDIT:** As Dave suggested, var_dump now shows me bool(false).
Can this be traced to more exact reason ?

Comment: What does a `var_dump($result)` show you? What is returned from `extractTo` is true/false.

Comment: Ah now i see, yes now it shows bool(false)

Comment: you can not echo $result before $zipArchive ->close();

Comment: Best guess is that the `extractTo` path you have specified is not working. I would try an explicit path and see if that works. Also, turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: "you can not echo $result before $zipArchive ->close();" - NOT TRUE